# Accessing SQL Server stored procedure output parameter in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a simple SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetRowCount

(
@count int=0 OUTPUT
)

AS
Select * from Emp where age>30;
SET @count=@@ROWCOUNT;

RETURN
```

I am trying to access the output parameter in the following C# code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=answers;Integrated Security=True";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.CommandText = "GetRowCount";
cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@count", SqlDbType.Int));
cmd.Parameters["@count"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader=cmd.ExecuteReader();
int ans = (int)cmd.Parameters["@count"].Value;
Console.WriteLine(ans);
```

But on running the code, a NullReferenceException is being thrown at the second last line of the code. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am new to SQL Procedures, so I referred [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306574/nl).

Comment: ankit i updated my code , you must just change your directive ExecuteNonQuery

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd suggest you put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into using blocks so that their proper disposal is guaranteed.

Also, if I'm not mistaken, the output parameters are only available after you've completely read the resulting data set that's being returned.

Since you don't seem to need that at all - why not just use `.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead? Does that fix the problem?

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=answers;Integrated Security=True"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetRowCount", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@count", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@count"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // *** since you don't need the returned data - just call ExecuteNonQuery
    int ans = (int)cmd.Parameters["@count"].Value;
    con.Close();

    Console.WriteLine(ans);
}
```

Also : since it seems you're only really interested in the row count - why not simplify your stored procedure to something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetRowCount
AS
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Emp WHERE age > 30;
```

and then use this snippet in your C# code:

```
    con.Open();

    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if(result != null)
    {
        int ans = Convert.ToInt32(result);
    }

    con.Close();
```

Comment: my bad, I have that line in my code, but somehow missed it here. I have edited the question

Comment: @ankit0311: updated my response - try using `.ExecuteNonQuery()` - does that fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just use ExecuteNonQuery , you can't use ExecuteReader with out parameter in this case

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Or if you want try with ExecuteScalar and ReturnValue

Comment: my bad, I have that line in my code, but somehow missed it here. I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify that it is a stored procedure not a query

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: my bad, I have that line in my code, but somehow missed it here. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

before calling it

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem, its the connection string.
But now, in the code:

```
 usuary = (string)cmd.Parameters["@USUARIO"].Value;
password = (string)cmd.Parameters["@CLAVE"].Value;
```

the compiler infomrs thats values are null...