# Visual Basic 2010: How to check if data is already in the SQL database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, vba

I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express and SQL Server 2008. I already connected the database I created and managed to input data on in. Im making a very simple registration system where I only put a idNumber and the password. The problem is I have to make the system detect whether the idNumber was already registered then executes a statement.

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=MYDATASOURCE;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    cmd.Connection = cn

    cn.Open()
    'this is where to put the code the search the database i think..
    cn.Close()
```

Ive been looking for days and it seems like vb.net is mostly used and answered but I have to use visual basic. I have no idea what code to put in there to read the database. I do think like c++ I have to retrieve the data and declare in on a variable then that is when I search it.

Comment: What you should learn is how to use this SqlCommand to send one. After this is only a matter of the right SQL request. I would recommend learning about SQL.

Comment: Take help from here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174399/accessing-sql-server-stored-procedure-output-parameter-in-c-sharp

Comment: Also this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I can provide you brief guidelines, but you need to do due diligence to accomplish this.job.

Write a stored procedure IsIdNumberExists that will check whether a idNumber exists in database tablet. Something like this....

var @recCount

Select @recCount = count(1) from yourTable where idNumber=@inputidNumber // pass it from UI

if @recCount=0
return false
return true

2 In your C# code, pass StoredProcedure name to cmd object.

3 Create a SqlParameter and attach it to cmd object

4 Execute cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

5 Get the return boolean object in C# and decide accordingly.